# Checking is SWF is loaded successfully

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm using SWF file in my HTML.
 
**How can I check if SWF file loaded successfully? 

or how can I check if SWF file exists from javascript?**  (I can't make any changes in SWF file.)

I have a callback in for my SWF object and I'm checking e.success but if SWf file doesn't exist it still returns true.

```
function myCallbackFn(e){
   console.log(e.success);
}

swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", "", "", "" ,myCallbackFn);
```

What else can I check?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your callback return true after adding the embedded code to the DOM; it doesn't check to see if the file exists.

Comment: I want to show SWF file only when everything is ok. If there is some problem with file or loading I musn't show SWF, instead of this I should show some other text.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a file exists on a remote server you can do something like this:

```
function DoesItExist(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status==200;
}
```

Just pass it the url of your file and it will return true if the file exists.

Comment: File will be in local machine. Not on a remote server

Comment: I wanted to say that it works via HTTP ...so it would work if your site is running on lets say localhost ...as long as the files are served by a http server(Apache, Nginx, etc). So the url has to be something like `http://localhost/yourfile.swf`.... not `file://C:/etc...`